# Object or array for the project

Tags: javascript

I have two variants to work with my objects full of data:

```
let global_obj = {
    "id0": { /*big object 0*/},
    "id1": { /*big object 1*/},
    "id2": { /*big object 2*/}
};
```

and:

```
let global_arr = [
    { id: "id0" /*big object 0*/},
    { id: "id1" /*big object 1*/},
    { id: "id2" /*big object 2*/}
];
```

So I can save my big objects full of data inside of a global array or a global object. Which way is better in terms of performace (looping through, deleting, adding new objects)?

I am going to address specific objects by their id very often, change objects' properties, loop trought them all.

Comment: Depends how you loop through them. If you ever have an id and need to find the associated object, first is probably best.

Comment: It may be more important to model your object according to business functionality.  Performance here may not  be a major factor.  Looking at the structure, an Array looks more appropriate.

Comment: How will you use it?

Comment: Both can be used while my personal preference is the first one.

Comment: There is no better. There is only the form that's more ideal for your use case, so you'll need to describe that in more detail. Sometimes it's worth storing it in both forms where the sub-objects themselves are not duplicated, but two references are kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an object in this case as finding an element by *id* is easier/faster. If index/order of elements is important, object don't help here and you need to use an array.

Basically:

- Objects: Keyed collections
- Arrays: Ordered collections

But regular objects and arrays are not the only options if the environment supports ES2015. ES2015 has introduces several APIs for working with collections: [Map, Set, WeakMap and WeakSet](https://javascript.info/map-set-weakmap-weakset).

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you'll be "addressing specific objects through their id's very often"; using an Object will be a wise choice for you. Since accessing an object's key is done in O(1) as compared to finding the object in an array, which will be O(n), hence Object will be better in performance.

Answer (score 1):

You should do what's more convenient for you, it most likely won't make a difference.

However, generally, if the top level object is small, the array is always faster than a hashtable/object (the size of the inner objects doesn't matter). If the top-level structure is big, then you should consider the big-o complexity for the operations you want to perform on the top-level structure. See http://bigocheatsheet.com/